# Why does Xcode 4.3 static analysis report a logic error with this code?

Tags: c++, xcode, exception, clang, static-analysis

I'm uncertain about why Xcode 4.3 reports "Logic error. Undefined or garbage value returned to caller" when running static analysis on the following C++ code. The error is reported to be at the line `return e;`.

```
enum MyEnum { MyEnumValue };

MyEnum myFunction() {
    try {
        throw MyEnumValue;
    } catch (MyEnum e) {
        return e;
    }

    return MyEnumValue;
}
```

Any clues??

Comment: Looks like it's just a bug/false positive in the analyzer.

Comment: Yeah that was my suspicion as well. I've filed a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Xcode 4.3 that seems to be fixed now in Xcode 4.4.